# Dependency cannot see its config during compilation

Tags: docker, elixir, config, elixir-mix

I'm trying to package an app in docker container. It has a dependency on [`authable`](https://github.com/mustafaturan/authable) hex package.

When running:

```
docker build --tag "testing:0.1" --file Dockerfile .
```

... I get the following compilation error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/authable/repo.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) missing :adapter configuration in config :authable, Authable.Repo
    lib/ecto/repo/supervisor.ex:50: Ecto.Repo.Supervisor.compile_config/2
    lib/authable/repo.ex:6: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6

could not compile dependency :authable, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile authable", update it with "mix deps.update authable" or clean it with "mix deps.clean authable"
```

The error indicates the Authable was not able to read & initialize its `repo` config during compilation:

1. [authable/repo.ex](https://github.com/mustafaturan/authable/blob/master/lib/authable/repo.ex#L6)
2. [config.exs](https://github.com/gmile/test_authable_docker/blob/master/config/config.exs#L54-L60)

I feel like there's something simple that I'm missing, but I can't figure our what it is.

A simple repo to reproduce the issue is here – https://github.com/gmile/test_authable_docker.

**Update**. Made it clear that the error occurs only when compiling during docker (e.g. everything is fine when compiling on host macOS).

Comment: Your project compiled just fine for me.

Comment: @JustinWood did you try compiling a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with your Dockerfile, where the `config/config.exs` is not yet available when trying to run `mix deps.compile`.

Original Dockerfile content:

```
# Install and compile project dependencies
COPY mix.* ./

RUN mix deps.get
RUN mix deps.compile
RUN mix ecto.create
RUN mix ecto.migrate -r Authable.Repo

# Add project sources
COPY . .
```

Changing this to copying the sources before doing `mix compile` solves this issue:

```
....
RUN mix deps.get

# Add project sources
COPY . .

RUN mix deps.compile
...
```

Comment: Thank you, Navin! That was a dumb mistake of mine

Comment: I think just adding `ADD config/config.exs ./config/` before `mix deps.compile` is enough, that way you don't have to recompile all dependencies every time any of your project source files change